# Questions about loading executables into memory

Tags: c, linux

So I'm working with the linux 0.11 kernel on a virtual machine, and I need to write a program that analyses executable files that are ran on that kernel. The files are in the format a.out. What I want to know is, how does the operating system decide where to load the file in (virtual?) memory? Is it decided by something called "base address", and if so, how come I can't seem to find any mention of it in the a.out header?

```
//where is base address?
struct exec {
  unsigned long a_magic;    /* Use macros N_MAGIC, etc for access */
  unsigned a_text;          /* length of text, in bytes */
  unsigned a_data;          /* length of data, in bytes */
  unsigned a_bss;           /* length of uninitialized data area for file, in bytes */
  unsigned a_syms;          /* length of symbol table data in file, in bytes */
  unsigned a_entry;         /* start address */
  unsigned a_trsize;        /* length of relocation info for text, in bytes */
  unsigned a_drsize;        /* length of relocation info for data, in bytes */
};
```

I tried looking for documentations about the format, but the only information I found just explains what each of these fields are, what values a_magic can have, etc.

I need to know about it because the program needs to print out file and line numbers when given an address in memory of an instruction in the executable, and the debug symbols only have their addresses as offsets (e.g. relative to the start of text section, etc).

Also, out of curiosity, I know that in C, "(void*)0" is NULL, which you can't dereference. How then would you get the content of memory address 0?

As you see, I know very little about linux kernel and operating systems in general, so please start from the basics...

I appreciate any help you can give, thanks.

Comment: This might answer one of your questions, [Is there any physical part of memory with the address of NULL(0)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932081)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base address is the `a_entry` field.

> Also, out of curiosity, I know that in C, "(void*)0" is NULL, which you can't dereference. How then would you get the content of memory address 0?

Any system that puts memory usable by a C program at address zero would have to make it work, somehow. While one can imagine possible ways to do this, I don't know of anyone who bothers. Virtual address zero is, for all intents and purposes, never used.

Comment: So how exactly would I get the offset address from the address of the instruction in process memory?

Comment: Subtract the base address from the memory address. But I'd strongly suggest using the actual mapping rather than the header anyway. (On linux, you can read the mappings from `/proc/<pid>/maps`.)

Comment: Could you tell us more about what the file does, how it relates to the problem, and why reading the a.out header isn't as good? thanks

Comment: The file tells you what mappings the running process has. It relates to the problem because that's exactly what you're trying to find out -- how the process has mapped the executable file. Reading the `a.out` header isn't as good because that can't tell you what the linker/loader actually did, only what the executable file asked it to do.

Answer (score 0):

The operating system can load the application at any location it chooses and then relocate the embedded addresses to be relative to that point. This relocation information is recorded in the [a.out](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/man51.pdf) file. The base address depends on the architecture and other details and is often non-zero.

If you look at a linker map file, you should see a symbol that is either at the beginning of the memory image, or at a fixed offset from it. At runtime, subtract this value from the actual addresses you note for debugging to get to the relative address of the position you are interested in.

Note, the symbols will not be present in the executable if your linker script strips them.

Comment: Is relocation relevant to an executable file (already linked) as well? How would I derive the information you mentioned from an executable file?

Comment: The a.out format is a hybrid that can be relinked if required (see the man page reference) and it optionally contains the symbols.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, out of curiosity, I know that in C, "(void*)0" is NULL, which you can't dereference. How then would you get the content of memory address 0?

Actually you can dereference NULL, but the results are not defined.  For convenience, most operating systems trap the access to help you debug pointer problems.

Also, memory location with address 0 in a process space is different from the memory location with address 0 in the 'hardware space'.  The 'pagination' support in the CPU and operating system are 'decoupling' the physical memory from the virtual memory.  It could happen that a virtual page be mapped at address 0, although there you usually have interrupt vectors and other special device memory and not real RAM anyway.